# Avoiding race conditions, but still being able to roll back

Tags: php, mysql, email, atomic, race-condition

I have a MySQL table with e-mails that are to be sent out.

On every page load, I check if there are any unsent e-mails, take a few of them and send them.

To prevent two simultaneous page loads from sending out the same e-mail, I'm thinking of doing something like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);

// Start blocking other page loads
$pdo->beginTransaction();
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT id, recipient, subject, body
    FROM emails WHERE sent = 0 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE");

$mail = $stmt->fetch();

if(false !== $mail)
    $pdo->exec("UPDATE emails SET sent = 1 WHERE id = $mail['id']");

// End blocking other page loads
$pdo->commit();

if(false !== $mail) {
    // Send e-mail
}
```

But what if execution is aborted after the commit, but before the e-mail is successfully sent? The e-mail will be market as sent, but will not actually have been sent. Of course I could wait with committing until after the e-mail has been sent, but that would cause a much longer blocking period. I'm sending the e-mails over SMTP, and sending a single e-mails takes around 10 seconds.

Do you have any ideas for how to solve this? One option might be to detect if the table is locked, and then just skip this entire step. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you check this in page loads because you can't use cronjobs on your webspace?

Answer (score 2):

Use a queuing system for this (redis, beanstalkd, RabbitMQ, etc) if you want this to scale in any way.

Sending emails based on page loads is a horrible idea in the long run, as you're not sending emails *asynchronously*, but slowing the page loads of random users down by a *lot*.

Here's an example:

Take a redis queue, and publish a json string including email IDs to be sent from them:

```
{"id":1, "job":"pending", "data": {"user": "foobar"}}
```

Make a cronjob to subscribe to this queue, and connect to the database and send the emails with those IDs.

If there is an error, you simply change job to `"job":"errored"`. On the next scheduled run of your email task, you handle it there.

There's quite a few queue libraries out there, and doing async tasks on a page load is the wrong way to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

You could mark it as *pending* before you send it and as *send* after you have send it. But you still need to think about the situation where something happens between setting it to *pending* and setting it to *send*.

If you don't want to send more then 'x' emails in parallel, then you could could think over counting the entries marked as *pending*  before you send the mail.

Something like that:

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);

// Start blocking other page loads
$pdo->beginTransaction();
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT id, recipient, subject, body
    FROM emails WHERE status = 'queued' LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE");

$mail = $stmt->fetch();

if(false !== $mail)
    $pdo->exec("UPDATE emails SET status = 'pending' WHERE id = $mail['id']");

// End blocking other page loads
$pdo->commit();

if(false !== $mail) {
    // Send e-mail
    if( $successfull ) {
       $pdo->exec("UPDATE emails SET status = 'sended' WHERE id = $mail['id']");
    } else {
       $pdo->exec("UPDATE emails SET status = 'failed' WHERE id = $mail['id']");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rolling back is an issue

`pending`,`successfull`,`failed` could be possible values for `status` field.

You have to check email delivery failures so you keep track that you actually delivered the emails (ex. 10 delivered out of 100 sended) , try working with `Maildir` and check for new mails for keywords such `failure`+`xyz@xyz.xyz` email then update database accordingly.

Working with large amount of email to send.

- make use of queues , probably the safest with threshold and "cooldown" after a group of emails was sent out.
- create a lock file to avoid race, *if it exists then go sleep else start sending*